# Disabling an element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.enableDisable = function() {
  this.disabled = true;
  return this;
}


document.querySelector("#loginButton").enableDisable();
```

```html
<input id="login" type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

I think I have am doing something wrong in my HTMLElement.prototype but not sure what

Can someone please help me?

Comment: The code works, what's wrong with it?

Comment: What type of element is `#loginButton`?

Comment: Why are you extending the prototype with a function? It could be easier for you to directly set `disabled` as an attribute!

Comment: Btw, `enableDisable` is a horrible name :-)

Comment: Login is a input. I updated the question

Comment: See my answer :)

Comment: Why not just `document.querySelector("#login").disabled = true;`?

Comment: `"message": "TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null",` your element's `id` is `login`, not `loginButton`.

Answer (score 0):

Input ID is `login`, you're querying document for element with ID `loginButton`.

Change:

```js
document.querySelector("#login").enableDisable()
```

Example: https://codepen.io/maxim_mazurok/pen/dyYKXYY